# How to disable load default template from this hook?

Tags: codeigniter, hook, codeigniter-2

I searched more and more for the best simple layout system like cakephp and I found this post

[CodeIgniter layout without using additional library](http://www.syahzul.com/blogs/item/codeigniter-layout-without-using-additional-library)

**now I need to disable this layout feature when I want that, but I don't know how to disable it?**
I think it has been disabled if I disabled the hook, any one know the way to do that or any way

Controller example

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public $layout = 'default';

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a templating system (and a rather strange and useless one at that but that's beside the point). Couldn't you just create different layouts and load the one you need in the different circumstances?

Comment: no i need to layout feature because Ci don't support this feature and i use this feature in the cakephp framework

Comment: What is the problem with using a library class to instantiate a templating system?<br />
The link you posted just creates a class that gets put in hook, how is it different from having a class sat in the libraries folder?

Comment: are you have good and simple  library to do that without changed codeigniter code format?...thank you

Comment: hook you can extend the core framework without hacking, if you want to perform  something before or after controller call or system you use hooks,Libraries are called with in system or controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi just give pass another layout name to $layout variable.

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public $layout = 'my_inner';

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

my_inner should be in application/views/layout directory

if you want to disable layout just pass null to $layout

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public $layout = null;

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

Comment: its really simple just pass null to $layout